# <iframe> depois de artigo no joomla

Tags: joomla

Fala gente... preciso de uma ajuda de quem já tem um pouco mais de experiência no joomla.

Vou resumir minha dúvida para vcs.
Atualmente estou trabalhando num site para livros ([cubomagi.co/bdl](http://cubomagi.co/bdl))
Quando o usuário entrar no link de algum livro, aparecerá as informações do livro, etc...
Exemplo: [A culpa é das estrelas](http://cubomagi.co/bdl/index.php/estante/34-fantasy/165-a-culpa-e-das-estrelas)

**Agora sim vem a dúvida real**

Para aparecer o livro, eu tô usando um iframe que eu coloco dentro do texto quando crio um artigo no joomla, contudo o tamanho fica limitado devido a configuração do artigo. Gostaria de saber se há algum jeito de eu colocar o iframe depois da tag article, se há algum plugin já criado que permita isso ou etc?

Comment: Gean editei minha resposta com mais informações, Acho que o caminho é formatar a `SideBar`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenta assim...
Você pode criar um **módulo do tipo "Custom"** *(infelizmente um para cada livro, pois cada um terá um `<iframe>` diferente)*.

Depois disso habilita esse Módulo na página do artigo do livro, ***não dentro do artigo, mas na página do artigo.***

Ai você escolhe uma posição para o módulo com o `<iframe>` do livro que fique abaixo do conteúdo do artigo.

Veja nas imagens para entender melhor.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Outra coisa que reparei é que o artigo tem um side bar que ocupa uma `col-sm-4` que é uma classe do Grid do **Bootstrap3**. E o `iframe` do Livro ocupa uma `col-sm-8`

**Grid do Bootstrap**

```
<link href="/bdl/templates/ja_moviemax/local/css/themes/cyan/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

**Disposição do conteúdo no Grid**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então no seu caso eu formataria esse `<div class="col-sm-4 article-sidebar">` com as informações do livro para ele ocupar um `col-sm-12` e deixaria o `iframe` do livre ocupar um `col-sm-12` também, como na imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Então no seu caso eu tentaria mudar o formato do *SideBar* e não tentar jogar o `iframe` para baixo na gambiarra.**

Comment: Essa foi minha primeira ideia para vincular os livros ao seu artigo, contudo o que trava é a quantidade de livro publicado no antigo site que eu terei que passar para o novo, são mais de 150 livros, então eu teria trabalho duplo para criar o artigo, o module. Contudo, meu outro problema é que: não serei eu que cuidarei do site depois de pronto, por isso queria deixar o mais fácil possível para a próxima pessoa, pois ela e muito leiga em relação ao joomla...

Comment: vou aderir a ideia,  ficou visivelmente bem melhor na dica que vc deu, obrigado Hugo. att

Comment: @GeanCarlos que bom que gostou da ideia, boa sorte com o projeto.